# Unable to get data from CDATA in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following simple piece of code:

```
NodeList nodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node vtvRespNode = nodeList.item(i);
            NodeList cardNodes = vtvRespNode.getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < cardNodes.getLength(); j++) {
                Node cardNode = cardNodes.item(j);
                Card card = vtvResponse.new Card();
                if (cardNode instanceof Element) {
                    String content = cardNode.getLastChild().getTextContent().trim();
                    if(cardNode.getNodeName().equals(CARD_TYPE)) {
                        Log.i(TAG,"cardType set for this card: "+content);
                    }
                    else if(cardNode.getNodeName().equals(TTL)) {
                        Log.i(TAG,"TTL set for this card: "+content);
                    }
                    else if(cardNode.getNodeName().equals(LOCAL_TIME_STAMP)) {
                        Log.i(TAG,"localtimeStamp set for this card: "+content);
                    }
                    else if(cardNode.getNodeName().equals(CARD_BLOB)) {
                        CharacterData child = (CharacterData) cardNode.getFirstChild();
                        if(child instanceof CharacterData){
                            Log.i(TAG,"cardNode is instanceof CharacterData");
                            content = child.getData();
                        }
                        Log.i(TAG,"blob set for this card: "+content);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now, I have this sample xml:

```
<VtvResp>
    <CI>
        <localts> 1233546 </localts>
        <ctype> 4 </ctype>
        <ttl> 76542 </ttl>
        <card> <![CDATA[{"timezone": 330.0, "date": "03/10/13", "windspeed": "15", "weather": "Partly Cloudy", "temperature":               "28", "time": "04:02", "city_name": "Bangalore", "country": "India", "day": "thursday", "meridian": "pm"}]]>
        </card>
    </CI>

</VtvResp>
```

Here, I'm not able to get the CDATA data from the xml. The last Log of the `else if` blob always returns a blank string and I'm not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Plz help !!

Comment: This is a side comment, but why are you checking if `child` is an instance of `CharacterData` _after_ you have already cast it. Isn't that a bit backwards? Regarding your actual question, I would recommend trying `String content = cardNode.getTextContent().trim();` (without the `.getLastChild()`) and skip that whole `CharacterData` business.

Comment: Yeah just now observed it..
My careless mistake..I've corrected it

Comment: Thanks JLRise..I got it working like you said.
But what I dont understand is - if we can get CDATA without using CharacterData, then why do people still sometimes use CharacterData ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code was not working was that your `card` element has three child nodes:

- A text node with a single space
- The CDATA node with a bunch of text
- A text node with a bunch of space

Your code was selecting the last child node (which was just blank space) to populate the `content` variable and the first node for the `child` variable, which was (a) not a CDATA node and (b) just empty space, and that explains the behavior you observed. The easy fix for this is to use the following to get `content` and skip all the `CharacterData` casting:

```
String content = cardNode.getTextContent().trim();
```

To answer your follow-up question, there may be times when people will want to be very precise and recognize a CDATA node as a CDATA node (and operate on separate text nodes individually), so the API provides capabilities to do this. But the `.getTextContent()` method allows getting the entire text content of an element, and that should do the job just fine in your case.